# How to import spring.xml resource relative to project?

Tags: java, xml, spring

I have a base `spring.xml/applicationContext.xml` that I'd like to import within extended configurations. How can I import it relative, if all xml configs are located in `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/`:

The full qualified works, but how to make it relative?

`<import resource="C:/Users/me/workspace/app/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContextBase.xml" />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to import the resources via classpath lookup:

```
<import resource="classpath:/applicationContextBase.xml" />
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does not: `nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [applicationContextBase.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Comment: How are you trying to run your app? Usually, a project should be built into some kind of artifact (e.g. JAR or EAR), which should be included by default into the classpath. So you shouldn't try to refer to the absolute path of the resources. What happens when you will deploy your app to another machine?

Comment: Eclipse run as > java application.

Comment: I see. This might be a problem. Try to build the project before running the main class. Also check in Eclipse in Run -> Run Configurations -> Classpath tab if your project is added as a User Entry